# Getting too many channels error for a period of time

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I have `16 queues` & `mulitple consumer servers` for those queues. I have `created` one `dedicated` channel for `each queue` to `consume` messages. `Consumer` & `dispatch` `channels` on each server share `same connection`.

---

When I `dispatch messages` to each queue, I do the following:

1. create a new channel
2. bind channel to the queue with proper routing
3. dispatch the message
4. close the channel

---

I have lots of incoming webhooks from Shopify & these webooks contents are dispatched to specific queues.

> While processing each message, I need make an API call to Shopify. Shopify API has rate limit. If I hit rate limit once, I redispatch all messages from the consumer back to rabbitmq with a delay header of 1 minute(time required to clear the API rate limit).

Now, when I have several consumers running with lots of messages in the queue & I re-dispatch those messages, I get `too many channels` error for a period of time. How can I avoid this error?

---

`I tried to keep 2 dedicated channels per queue:`

1. for conusmer purpose only
2. for dispatch purpose only

For, 16 queues, & around 11 consumer servers. This way, I always have to keep `352` channel open. This `caues CPU utilization on rabbitmq host server to reach >90%` which is also an issue. As the server can crash any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem after digging through the `RabbitMQ documentation`.

Instead of creating a new channel for each dispatch, I `created a single channel` & `kept it alive` for the `entire` connection `session`. When `creating` the channel, I `asserted` all the `exchanges` that would be used by my queues.

Then I just `publish` the messages to the `desired exchange` with the `routing key`. As my queues are already bonded with the exchanges & listen for messages with a given routing key, the messages end up in the correct queue!

This way I can maintain just `01` connection & only `01` channel per server!